# Pre-set replies for Outlook out of office assistant?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

My company would like employees to have an option of choosing from pre-set messages for their out of office assistant instead of letting them type their own.

I can't see to figure out an easy way to accomplish this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into writing a VSTO add-in for something like that.  I've written a few, but not one specific to this task.

StackOverflow (sister site) is a great place to ask for help in something like this.   There are also a few good books I can recommend to get you started.